# How do I repair this damage to metal facade detail?

Tags: roofing, masonry

Metal facade detail on 1950 brick building.  Two sides, holes in both.  Looks like it is coming away from the wall as well.

I have no idea how to restore this, I am intending to staple up some mesh to prevent any more wildlife, but that is just a stop gap measure.

Any input/advice would be appreciated.  Im pretty handy but this one is not something I have done or seen done.

The other side was worse but the size requirements for pictures on this site are pretty low.
[image]

Comment: So based on the rust the whole "molding/trim" is really formed sheet metal? As for the birds nesting on the ledge under the overhang, that's pretty much what it's there for. I *finally* got my barn swallows to move up to a ledge after the 3rd time their nest over the garage door fell down. I'm quite happy to provide a home in exchange for their insect-devouring services. One on a more-stable surface should work out better for all of us.

Comment: Or you have squirrel holes into the inside corner? Yeah, that's not live and let live territory.

Comment: Yea i dont mind the birds, however the gaping holes are a problem.  It is formed sheet metal i suppose.  if it was wood id have no problem, but i dont know enough about it to even research properly.

Comment: *details* don't have to be there. Just saying. Likely the brick underneath it is a different color tho.

Comment: For the rusty areas on the sides, you could sand down to good metal (assuming it is not rusting out from the inside) and prime the area, then repaint that section of trim after standard painting prep.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a jut out in the brick?  Also a piece of galvanized tin as a cap on top that is not tucked into brick course. It doesn’t look like the tin on top has any drip edge formed into it I would remove the tin. Plan A would be make the top solid with some type of wood material. Cover it with ice and water shield. Then, put real drip edge around the perimeter.  Finally add a layer of lead (first choice) or coil stock aluminum shaped to fit.  Shouldn’t need any caulk at that point but I would have a tube paintable stuff handy if needed
RPK